# NPE while creating alerdialog

Tags: android

I am calling method `AlertUser.alertUser(getActivity());` which has alertDialog from fragment but it throws NPE error

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    if(flag==false)
                        {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    AlertUser.alertUser(getActivity());
                    cancel(true);
                        }
                    }
                }, 30000);
```

alertUser method:

```
public static void alertUser(Context context)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 


        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection failure...!"+"\n");

        alertDialog.setMessage("\n"+"It looks like you have lost network connection. Please check your network connection or wait to re-connect"+"\n");





        // Setting  "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {


                    /*Intent noNetwork=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(noNetwork,1443);*/



            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

logcat

```
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at com.abs.deliveryboy.AlertUser.alertUser(AlertUser.java:11)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at com.abs.deliveryboy.NewOrdersFragment$NewOrderTask$1.run(NewOrdersFragment.java:159)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4800)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-05 15:47:06.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12050):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's at line 11 of AlertUser.java?

Answer (score 2):

The context you passed to `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor is `null` and hence the NPE.

Fragment `getActivity()` will return `null` if the fragment is not attached to an activity. Since you're posting an asynchronous runnable to a handler, there's no guarantee the fragment being attached to an an activity when the runnable runs.

You should pass in a valid activity context as an argument to your runnable insted of querying it with `getActivity()`. Note that holding onto activity references is an easy way to get significant memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As @FD_ said, you can't start an alert dialog from a background thread. When you use `getActivity()` in a background thread, it returns null, hence the NPE. You're passing a null object to the other method. Better do it on the same activity / thread.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this..

```
public static void alertUser(Context context)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 


        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection failure...!"+"\n");

        alertDialog.setMessage("\n"+"It looks like you have lost network connection. Please check your network connection or wait to re-connect"+"\n");





        // Setting  "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {


                    /*Intent noNetwork=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(noNetwork,1443);*/



            }
        });
//previously it was like this alertDialog.show(); but it should be like this
        alertDialog.create.show();
    }
```